# Same profile names in Maven-setting and POM

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

This is my first day using Maven's build profiles. I have profiles in following files:

1. pom.xml
2. Maven-settings (%USER_HOME%/.m2/settings.xml)

For curiosity I have created one profile in both files with same id(local_deploy), only difference being in one property (e.g. tomcat.pwd).

Profile in POM looks like below:

```
<profile>
        <id>local_deploy</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <tomcat.host>localhost</tomcat.host>
            <tomcat.port>8080</tomcat.port>
            <tomcat.url>http://${tomcat.host}:${tomcat.port}/manager/text</tomcat.url>
            <tomcat.user>admin</tomcat.user>
            <tomcat.pwd>admin</tomcat.pwd>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Profile in Maven setting looks like below:

```
<profile>
    <id>local_deploy</id>
    <properties>
      <tomcat.host>localhost</tomcat.host>
      <tomcat.port>8080</tomcat.port>
      <tomcat.url>http://${tomcat.host}:${tomcat.port}/manager/text</tomcat.url>
      <tomcat.user>admin</tomcat.user>
      <tomcat.pwd>wrongpwd</tomcat.pwd>
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

Please note, Profile in Maven setting is not listed in `<activeProfiles>`.

When I try to install my application using following command

```
mvn clean install -P local_deploy help:active-profiles
```

My application gets deployed with following output on console:

```
The following profiles are active:
local_deploy (source: external)
local_deploy (source: <my groupId>:<my artifactId><version>)
```

I am going through [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) documentation and it says that

```
Take note that profiles in the settings.xml takes higher priority than profiles in the POM
```

So, I assume my deployment should have failed because of incorrect password in Maven Setting. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version of maven 3 are you using?

Comment: I tried on maven 3.1.1 and 3.3.9 and indeed settings profile always override properties of a profile having the same name in a sample pom. So documentation is right, did you get further details about the behavior you reported?

Comment: So, you had same profile ids and both of them active?

Comment: Did you have any chance to try the code posted in my answer or review this behavior?

Comment: @A. Di Matteo, Thanks for detailed answer. You are right, profile in settings.xml gets preference. I verified this after rebuilding the setup. Sorry for late reply, I was just trying out what went wrong with my previous set up. Anyways, it turns out that, I was changing the tomcat admin password at wrong place. The tomcat-maven-plugin is using server configured(deep down) in setting.xml which I ignored by mistake. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample pom I used:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>profiles-sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>print-hello</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="msg" value="${hello}" />
                                <property name="msg2" value="${hello2}" />
                                <echo message="hello from build: ${msg}, ${msg2}" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>p2</id>
            <properties>
                <hello>from-pom</hello>
                <hello2>from-pom-again</hello2>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Defining in my settings:

```
<profile>
    <id>p2</id>
    <properties>
        <hello>from-settings</hello>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

So, note: two profiles with the same name, on POM and settings, defining the same `hello` property. However, the one in the POM defines one additional property, `hello2`.

Then, running:

```
mvn test -Pp2 help:active-profiles
```

I got as part of the build output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.5:run (print-hello) @ profiles-sample ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] hello from build: from-settings, from-pom-again
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building profiles-sample 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:active-profiles (default-cli) @ profiles-sample ---
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.sample:profiles-sample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

 - p2 (source: external)
 - p2 (source: com.sample:profiles-sample:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, from the Maven Help Plugin we actually know that both profiles were actives and that's true, because as part of the Antrun we got both properties (`hello` from the profile of the settings and `hello2` from the profile of the pom).
Hence, the two profiles were actives at the same time, their properties got merged (because `hello` is sharing the same name), the property from the settings took priority over the property from the POM, then the additional property of the POM got correctly in as well.

So, I couldn't reproduce the scenario you mentioned. I would suggest to double check settings and pom and add an additional property to play with.